# How to implement custom fallback function with input fields, text and submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm new to Dropzonejs and javascript/jQuery. I have spent some time playing with it and set up a dropzone which works great, but I need to create custom fallback function with 2 text inputs, 1 textarea, 1 checkbox and a submit button.

I do not now what to do next after I have put

```
<div class="fallback"></div>
```

into my form.

I have also created:

```
fallback: function() {

} // end of fallback
```

in options.mydropzone

Here is where I'm stuck. I need some hints to complete me custom fallback function.

Comment: A fallback from what, to what and when?

Comment: Sorry, when Browser does not support File API (drag&drop) I want to display a custom form e.g. IE9 users and safari < 6 do not get drag & drop form to submit. So I want to use fallback function in Dropzonejs and create custom upload form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your current form within a div

```
<div id="generalForm">
<form name='form1' .....>
</div>
```

Create a second form that you want to use as the fallback and wrap that in a div also

```
<div id="specialForm" style='display:none'>
<form name="form1" .... >
</div>
```

In your fallback function you would use

```
fallback: function() {
  document.getElementById('generalForm').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('specialForm').style.display='block';
}
```

Is that what you are wanting?

Answer (score 4):

Dropzone actually does this out of the box, you do not need to create this behavior. You just have to place a div with class='fallback' within the form, that holds an input for older browsers:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```